# Scraping e commerce using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, html-parsing

I am using **scrapy** to scrape Amazon website just for learning. When we shop category wise, we get a list of products, and when we click on a product we get details of that product. I have done the basic part of scraping details out of product list like a product name , a price and their links. but I want these **scraped** links to be used then and there, and detail page of each product should be scraped in that program itself.

```
class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?me=A1NZU6VUR85CVU&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonscrapyItem()
        all_div_quotes = response.css('body')
        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            product = quotes.css('.a-color-base.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()
            price = quotes.css('.a-offscreen').css('::text').extract()
            brand = quotes.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract()
            asin = quotes.css(
                '.sg-col-20-of-24.s-result-item.sg-col-0-of-12.sg-col-28-of-32.sg-col-16-of-20.sg-col.sg-col-32-of-36.sg-col-12-of-16.sg-col-24-of-28::attr(data-asin)').extract()
            productlink = quotes.css('.a-link-normal.a-text-normal').css('::attr(href)').extract()

            items['product'] = product
            items['price'] = price
            items['brand'] = brand
            items['asin'] = asin
            items['productlink'] = productlink

            yield items

        next_page_link = response.css('.a-last a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page_link)

        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, Amazon can detect crawlers and they will block you.

```
class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon_spider"


    def start_requests(self):
        page_links = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?me=A1NZU6VUR85CVU&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P', ]
        pages = 2
        page_domain = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?i=merchant-items&me=A1NZU6VUR85CVU&page=2&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&qid=1584935116&ref=sr_pg_"
        while page != 4: # 3 is the last page and it will stop making link when pages = 4
            link = page_domain + str(page)
            page_links.append(link)
            pages+=1

        #request all the pages
        for page in page_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        #scraped all product links
        domain = "https://www.amazon.co.uk"
        link_products = response.xpath('//h2/a/@href').extract()
        for link in link_products:
            product_link = domain + link
            yield scrapy.Request(url=product_link, callback=self.parse_contents)


    def parse_contents(self, response):
        #scrape needed information
        productlink = response.url
        product = response.xpath('//span[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        price = response.xpath('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()').extract()[0]

        ### I use try, cause amazon dont have a fixed value for brand
        try:
            brand = response.xpath('//a[@id="bylineInfo"]/text()').extract()[0]
        except IndexError:
            brand = response.xpath('//a[@id="brand"]/text()').extract()[0]

        items = AmazonscrapyItem()
        items['product'] = product
        items['price'] = price
        items['brand'] = brand
        # items['asin'] = asin # I dont know what are you trying to crawl here, sorry
        items['productlink'] = productlink

        yield items
```

Comment: what i wanted is that , when we get the product links ,i want to open those product links for each product and extract data from table containing more product details like weight and rank etc. for each product link. @bonifacio_kid

Comment: I want to create a new function in which product links will be requested and data from there will be saved along with these 5 parameters